Installer 24.04 crash not working
I can't install any Ubuntu 24.04, the program immediately crashes when 23.10 installed without problems, how can I resolve the situation, I must have a UEFI distribution because my mini PC won't let me choose another mode.

Did you mean the installer immediately crashes? At what point? Is there an error message?

Thanks, after downloading the ISO via torrent, I start it via USB stick, and after running for 5-10 minutes, the installer gives me an image of a road sign, which tells me to restart the computer and try again. No error messages.
Thanks again.
